# vb.net Convert string of military time to standard time

Tags: vb.net

So I need to make this to standard time but I cant find an easy way.

```
Private completedtime1 As String
  completedtime1 = oXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
```

I need it to take the time and make it HH:mm example 0.001388 which is like 2 mins

Comment: Help us please. Do you want to convert from HH:MM to float, is it? Try `DateTime.Now.ToOADate()`

Comment: Is it military time format `0.001388`?

Comment: Isn't military time just a 24-hour clock?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert from double to Date, you need to use

```
Dim j as double = DateTime.Now.ToOADate()
```

[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx)

To convert from Date to double, you should use `FromOADate()`

```
Dim k as Datetime = DateTime.FromOADate(j)
```

[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)